# Microsoft CNG - Create a self signed certificate in memory using BCrypt functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cryptography, x509, cng

I'm using the Microsoft CNG Cryptography API and I'm trying to create a self signed certificate.

We have existing code which uses the [`CertCreateSelfSignCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certcreateselfsigncertificate) method, combined with [`NCryptOpenStorageProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptopenstorageprovider) and [`NCryptCreatePersistedKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptcreatepersistedkey) to create the key pair.

The problem I'm facing now, is that the above combination creates a key which ends up in the windows crypto store. I explicitly don't want to store keys there, I want the certificate and private key to both be in-memory as I plan to then write them to encrypted/protected storage of our own choosing.

From what I've been able to tell, the BCrypt family of functions is designed for in-memory use, and indeed I can use [`BCryptGenerateKeyPair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgeneratekeypair) to do this, but then the `CertCreateSelfSignCertificate` doesn't work as it expects a key storage provider.

Is there any way to solve this? I was thinking either to try make a tempory in-memory key storage provider somehow, or else to do it the hard way and build the entire X509 certificate blob myself using a complex chain of calls to [`CryptEncodeObjectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptencodeobjectex). Documentation/reference and example code on this kind of stuff is terrible and I've struggled to find anything despite extensive googling :-(

Any help for different ideas or example code that might work would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is the exact code from one of my applications that I make (except a few changes to the app name in the code.)

It creates a self signed certificate in memory and adds it to the local system store. A few tweaks and you can get the certificate context itself. It uses the CNG Next Generation API to stay modern.

```
bool GenerateSelfSignedCertificate()
{
    auto result{ false };
    CERT_NAME_BLOB nameBlob{ 0 };
    CERT_EXTENSIONS certExtensions{ 0 };
    NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE providerHandle{ 0 };
    NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle{ 0 };
    PCCERT_CONTEXT certContext{ nullptr };
    HCERTSTORE certStore{ nullptr };
    CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO keyProvInfo{
        const_cast<LPWSTR>(L"MyService_Key"), const_cast<LPWSTR>(MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER),
        0, NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG, 0, nullptr, AT_KEYEXCHANGE
    };

    if (!CertStrToNameW(X509_ASN_ENCODING, L"CN=MyService", 0, nullptr, nameBlob.pbData,
        &nameBlob.cbData, nullptr))
        goto fail;
    nameBlob.pbData = new UCHAR[nameBlob.cbData];
    if (!CertStrToNameW(X509_ASN_ENCODING, L"CN=MyService", 0, nullptr, nameBlob.pbData,
        &nameBlob.cbData, nullptr))
        goto fail;
    if (NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&providerHandle, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto fail;
    if (NCryptCreatePersistedKey(providerHandle, &keyHandle, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, L"MyService_Key",
        AT_KEYEXCHANGE, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto fail;
    if (NCryptFinalizeKey(keyHandle, NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto fail;
    certContext = CertCreateSelfSignCertificate(keyHandle, &nameBlob, 0, &keyProvInfo, nullptr,
        nullptr, nullptr, &certExtensions);
    if (!certContext)
        goto fail;
    certStore = CertOpenSystemStoreW(NULL, L"MY");
    if (!certStore)
        goto fail;
    if (!CertAddCertificateContextToStore(certStore, certContext, CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING, nullptr))
        goto fail;
    result = true;

fail:
    delete[] nameBlob.pbData;
    if (keyHandle)
        OutputDebugStringW(L"NCryptFinalizeKey successfully finalized the key for use in the certificate.\r\n");
    if (providerHandle)
        NCryptFreeObject(providerHandle);
    if (certStore)
        CertCloseStore(certStore, 0);
    if (certContext)
        CertFreeCertificateContext(certContext);
    return result;
}
```

Please let me know if this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!

I modified the above code to set the keyName to nullptr, and it appears to work. Evidenced by if I run it twice with a non-null keyName, then the second call fails with NTE_EXISTS, however with a null keyName it succeeds every time, indicating an ephemeral key. Exactly what I was after!

Comment: @OrionEdwards No problem, glad to hear it works exactly as you want it! You are right, I should have said that I designed the code above for one-time creation of a certificate with the name object, and I'm glad you figured it out 

Comment: So just to be clear, did you replace "MyService_Key" with `NULL` in the calls to `CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO` initializing and `NCryptCreatePersistedKey`? I'm able to create an in-memory NCrypt key but I can't pass in the `CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO` without a key name.

Comment: Hi @ArushAgarampur can you help me to get it work! I am creating the certificate but when I am using that certificate it fails, I want to create a certificate with ECDSA algorithm